# Почему не работает эта программа?

Tags: c++

```
    int random_number(int number) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 1; i++) {
        number = 1 + (rand() % 100);
    }
    return number;
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    srand(time(0));
    int value;
    cout << "Загадайте число от 0 - 100" << endl;
    cout << "Загадали? Это число? - ";
    random_number(value);
}
```

Comment: Что в вашем понимании "не работает"? Написана она, конечно, весело, но вполне работоспособна (делает то, что вы сами написали). Было бы смешно, правда, написав программу для редактирования текста, требовать от нее, чтоб она кино показывала :) Так и у вас - она делает в точности то, что написано...

Comment: для чего цикл в функции? Не считаете, что он бесполезен? Ну вернула функция значение,  которое вы даже не используете.  И что дальше?..  Программа работает, она делает то, что вы написали

Comment: Что значит "весело"?)

Comment: Зачем вы передаете в `random_number` параметр? Во-первых, вы его все равно не используете, во-вторых, передаете туда мусор. Зачем у вас цикл из 2 итераций, ведь результат действия первой вы все рано игнорируете? Я уж молчу, что 0 вы никогда не угадаете, это мелочь :) Словом, набор какой-то ерунды, а не программа...

Comment: Это значит что вы  просто написали не напрягаясь  по поводу резулььтата и пользовательям не напрягаете тем, чего вы хотели добиваться

Comment: меня так Sololearn учил...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может так?

```cpp
int random_number(int number) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 1; i++) {
        number = 1 + (rand() % 100);
    }
    return number;
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    srand(time(0));
    int value;
    cout << "Загадайте число от 0 - 100" << endl;
    cin >> value;
    cout << "Загадали? Это число? - " << random_number(value);
}
```

Comment: так просто выводится некое случайное число. Не думаю, что для этого недостаточна однострочная программа cout << rand() % 100;

Comment: Я просто добавил пропущенные cin, cout

Comment: что вы вводите значение  для  value, ничего не меняет, всеравно оно инициализируется новым значением в функции. Пока неизвестна  цель программы, результат == xz

Comment: Ну и нафига тут `value`? Ваша программа ничуть не лучше - по бессмысленности - исходной...

Comment: )))))))))))))))